# Prove there is no solution for a specific type of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

On an article about Group theory -if I understood correctly- the writer came with a claim to which he/she provided no proof of.

If $p(α)$ is a polynomial construed as $c_0+c_1α+c_2α^2…+c_nα^n$ where each $c_i$ is a rational number, and $α$ is equivalent to the $(n+1)$th root of $k$, being $k$ an integer, then $p(α)$ cannot be equal to $0$.

---

My shot at proving the latter statement is to write $p(α)$ as $(r_0/s_0)+(r_1/s_1)α+(r_2/s_2)α^2…+(r_n/s_n)α^n$, where each $r_i$ and $s_i$ are integers.

If $p(α) = 0$, then

$(r_0/s_0)+(r_1/s_1)α+(r_2/s_2)α^2…+(r_n/s_n)α^n = 0$

$(s_1*s_2*...*s_n)[(r_0/s_0)+(r_1/s_1)α+(r_2/s_2)α^2…+(r_n/s_n)α^n] = 0(s_1*s_2*...*s_n)$

$b_0+b_1α+α^2…+b_nα^n = 0$, all $b_i$ are integers

$b_1α+b_2α^2…+b_nα^n = -b_0$

From there it seems somehow intuitive that the equality is simply false. But I was not able to prove it, and that is why I'm asking for help.

Any thoughts/ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on the $c_i$ or $k$? It seems like $c_i = 1\;\forall i$ makes $\alpha = \exp[2\pi i/(n+1)]$ give $p(\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: Well, α has to be the (n+1)th root of k, being both (n+1) and k integers, so if exp[2πi/(n+1)] is equivalent to an α, then you would have disproved my statement. Maybe I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not true in general. However, it *is* true if $k$ is a prime. Indeed, under this assumption, $x^{n+1}-k$ is irreducible (in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$), by Eisenstein's criterion. So $k$ is an algebraic number of degree $n+1$ and therefore it cannot be a root of a non-null polynomial with rational coefficients and degree smaller than $n+1$.